# DataSet and DataRow for Net Standard 1.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm trying to port an pcl to net-standard stable version (1.5).

The `System.Data.DataTable` I could fix with the nuget package of `System.Data.Common` v4.3.0. But is there a workaround to fix `System.Data.DataSet` and `System.Data.DataRow` namespaces without targeting the net-standard preview version 2.0?

Or maybe an valid refactor type to use for it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use DataSet/DataRow as these classes are not present in netstandard1.5. If your library uses these types in public API you cannot just replace these classes with your own "System.Data.DataSet" or "System.Data.DataRow" because these custom types will not match real framework classes what will come back in netstandard2.0.

If you use they internally you may rewrite the code to use IDataReader and IDbCommand directly, or use 3rd-party data access library like NReco.Data that provides its own simplified RecordSet structure that is very similar to DataTable/DataRow (but it is not exactly the same of course).